# How to authenticate user in WebApi 2 ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to make a simple login page in **ASP.NET** by using `WebApi 2` but actually by searching on the web i found that i should use middleware as `OWIN` for Token authentication but actually it works only if the application is in **ASP.NET Core**..

So i thought to simply on Login store the login data in Session **BUT surprise** Session is not allowed to be used in WebApi 2...

So actually my code looks like the following, here is the jquery code where i make `POST` request to the server and store some data in `sessionStorage`

```
    function logIn(username,password) {
        let data = { username: username, password: password };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            url: 'api/utenti/login/',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (d) {
                if (d === null) {
                    alert("Username o password errate!");
                } else {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("id", d.id);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("username", d.username);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("piva", d.piva);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("negozi", d.negozi);
                    sessionStorage.setItem("role", d.role);
                    window.location.replace("https://localhost:44300/");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my `Login Controller`

```
<RoutePrefix("api/utenti")>
Public Class UtentiController
    Inherits ApiController

    <HttpPost()>
    <Route("login")>
    Public Function GetLogin(ByVal data As Utenti.Login) As Utenti
        If data.username = "" Or data.password = "" Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim utenti As Utenti = New Utenti
        Return utenti.UserExists(data.username, data.password)

    End Function

End Class
```

And here is my `Utenti.Class` where i check if the user exist or not and return the details of the user get from DB

```
Public Class Utenti

    Public Class Login
        Public Property username As String
        Public Property password As String

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)

            Me.username = username
            Me.password = password

        End Sub

    End Class


    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property piva As String
    Public Property negozi As String
    Public Property role As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal username As String, ByVal piva As String, ByVal negozi As String, ByVal role As String)

        Me.id = id
        Me.username = username
        Me.piva = piva
        Me.negozi = negozi
        Me.role = role

    End Sub

    Public Function UserExists(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Utenti
        Dim SQLConnect As String = "Server=192.168.100.220;Port=3306;Database=visualintelligence;Uid=root;Pwd=block;"
        Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)
        Try
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT id_ut, username_ut, piva_ut, negozi_ut, role_ut FROM utenti WHERE username_ut = @Username AND password_ut = @Password", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password)
            cn.Open()
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Dim utente As Utenti = ConvertReader(reader)

            Return utente
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            cn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Function ConvertReader(ByVal reader As MySqlDataReader)
        Dim utenti As Utenti = New Utenti
        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                utenti.id = reader.Item("id_ut")
                utenti.username = reader.Item("username_ut")
                utenti.piva = reader.Item("piva_ut")
                utenti.negozi = reader.Item("negozi_ut")
                utenti.role = reader.Item("role_ut")
            End While
            Return utenti
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

So from my code above how could i make a simple authentication? i'm not asking for the code but any suggestion would be appreciated as it's my first Api based login

Comment: Please do not store passwords as plain text, Salt and Hash.